# How to embed parameters into AWS Lambda GET request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

So say my request url to get all the Users at Location 4 is something like

```
./Location/Users?locationId=4 or ./Location/Users/4
```

but we would of course prefer to structure the request url like this:

```
./Location/4/Users
```

however, every single AWS help document and help question I can find on here uses the first syntax, so I am unsure how to proceed. It seems like there should be a way to do this, as it is a very common design pattern, but AWS seems to lock you in to only being able to append to the *./Users* path instead of being able to prepend the argument.

[image: I think configuring API Gateway to accept a parameter in this way would have to change the way they display the resources here]

To be clear, the first request syntax is working, but I'm not sure how to adjust the syntax to a more industry-standard way of doing it since embedding the parameter in the middle of the url instead of at the end would fundamentally change the Amazon Resource Name.

There's probably something simple that I'm missing here though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Api gateway indeed supports URl like `Location/{locationId}/Users`. You first need to create `locationId` as a child resource and then create `users` as a child resource under that.

#### Steps

- Click `Location`, and goto actions and click `create resource`.
- fill the details of your new resource

  resource name - give a meaningful name

  resource path - `{locationId}`
- repeat the same to add `Users` under `LocationId`

Comment: is that what you are looking for

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your help! love you bby